# in Asterisk 10, how can i use MessageSend() in dialplan to send messages outside calls between two SIP phones between two different Asterisk instances

Tags: asterisk

I can use MessageSend() in dialplan to send messages outside calls between two SIP phones in the same Asterisk. However, I can’t find any document or example to route messages between different Asterisk instances. If I have a phone with extension “123” connect to Asterisk server 10.0.1.105, I am not able to route the message using  “exten =>123, 1, MessageSend(sip:123@10.0.1.105)” from other Asterisk servers. Could you give me some advices or point me to related documents on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exten => s,1,NoOp(blah!)
exten => s,n,NoOp(${MESSAGE(from)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${MESSAGE(to)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${MESSAGE(body)})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${SIPFROMUSER})
exten => s,n,Set(SIPFROMUSER=${MESSAGE(from):4:-13})
exten => s,n,NoOp(${SIPFROMUSER})
exten => s,n,MessageSend(${MESSAGE(to):0:-13},${SIPFROMUSER})
```